# Reponds.appendHeader not work on IE

Tags: c#, redirect

i m using C#.
with this syntax Response.AppendHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=../Ordres.aspx"); work on Firefox and Chrome

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PdfExportOptions opts = new PdfExportOptions();
                            opts.ShowPrintDialogOnOpen = true;
                            xtraReport_Pricipal.ExportToPdf(ms, opts);
                            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            byte[] report = ms.ToArray();
                            Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            Page.Response.Clear();
                            Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(report, 0, report.Length);
                            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            ms.Close();
                        }
                    }

Response.AppendHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=../Ordres.aspx");
```

but not on Internet explorer. how can i redirect the page after 2 sec on IE ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
```